# Action and Action integral: Different kinds of variational principles

Tags: classical-mechanics, terminology, variational-principle, action

What are the difference between:

1. the action $\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}(L+H) dt$ that we use in the *principle of least action,* and
2. the action integral $\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}L dt$ that we use in *Hamilton's variational principle?*

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* Section 8.6.
2. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* Chapter 2.

Comment: I've never seen anything defined as $\int L+H\,dt$, could you cite a source that uses this form?

Comment: $H\equiv pv-L$, and so $L+H=pv$, and so $\int (L+H)dt = \int pvdt = \int pdq$

Answer (score 12):

The more common names for what you are talking about are the [abbreviated action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_action#Abbreviated_action_.28functional.29)

$$S_0[q] := \int p \mathrm{d}q$$

versus the [action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_action#Action_.28functional.29)

$$ S[q] := \int_{t_1}^{t_2}L(q,\dot q,t)\mathrm{d}t$$

Both are used in different formulations of classical mechanics, and deliver a different "flavor" of solutions. On both one can do variations calculus and obtains the classical trajectory $q_{cl}$ as the extremum of the action.

The abbreviated action obeys [Maupertuis' principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis%27_principle) and gives you the classical path provided you know the conserved energy along the trajectory and the start- and endpoints.

The action's extrema are found by the usual Euler-Lagrange equations and gives you the classical path provided you know the start- and endtimes as well as points.

Now, what has the abbreviated action to do with $L + H$? Observe that

$$\int p \mathrm{d}q =\int p \dot q \mathrm{d}t = \int (L + H) \mathrm{d}t$$

since $L$ and $H$ are Legrendre transforms w.r.t. $\dot q$ resp. $p$ of each other.

Answer (score 6):

As user ACuriousMind correctly writes:

1. What Goldstein calls *the principle of least action* $\int p~\mathrm{d}q$ is usually called [*Maupertuis' principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis%27_principle) or *the principle of abbreviated action*.
2. What Goldstein calls *the Hamilton's variational principle* is often also called the [*the principle of least/extremal/stationary action*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) $\int L~\mathrm{d}t$.

This is also explained in a footnote in Goldstein, Section 8.6. At the physical level, besides the different appearances, the important thing is to realize that different quantities are kept fixed in the two [variational principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_principle) 1 and 2.

Also note that confusingly the Hamilton's principle is a variational principle in the [Lagrangian formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) (as opposed to the [Hamiltonian formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics)).

Finally, let us remark that the word *action* has several different meanings in [physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_%28physics%29) and [mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action).