# How to derive the true spatial paths (orbits) from the Jacobi-Maupertuis condition?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

How can differential equations describing a physical object's true spatial paths (orbits) be derived from the *time-independent* Jacobi-Maupertuis principle of least action?  According to [this](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Principle_of_least_action#Statements_of_Hamilton_and_Maupertuis_Principles), it is possible.

> The time-independent version of Maupertuis' principle yields (Lanczos 1970, Landau and Lifshitz 1969) corresponding differential equations for the true spatial paths (orbits).

I guess I am looking for equations analogous to the Euler-Lagrange conditions, but for true spatial paths (orbits) instead of true trajectories as a function of time.

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74674/) PSE post is relevant, but is concerned with the derivation of equations of motion, whereas here I am concerned with the derivation of true spatial paths (orbits).

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): It seems the question formulation is mixing the following non-standard terminology used in the [linked Scholarpedia article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Principle_of_least_action): 1. _a true path_ = a parametrized on-shell curve, i.e. a function of time; and 2. _a true orbit_ = an un-parametrized on-shell curve, i.e. not a function of time.

Comment: @Qmechanic I have tried to address your comment with an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments to the question (v4):

1. Recall first of all, that in the [principle of stationary action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action), the initial and final times, $t_i$ and $t_f$, are fixed; while in the [abbreviated action principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis'_principle), the initial and final times, $t_i$ and $t_f$, are free, but the initial and final positions, $q^j_i$ and $q^j_f$, together with the energy $E$, are fixed.
2. There exist reparametrization-invariant formalisms. However, let us here just outline an elementary pedestrian approach. This consists in picking one of the position coordinates (which possibly after a relabelling we call) $q^1\equiv \lambda$ to play the role of the curve parameter $\lambda$. The other position coordinates $q^2, \ldots, q^n$ are now viewed as functions of $q^1$.
3. In other words, we view the curve as a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function). The bad news is that this might only work locally, and we may have to patch solutions together globally.
4. The good news is that $q^1\equiv \lambda$ is naturally fixed at the initial and final position, $q^1_i$ and $q^1_f$.
5. Now let there be given one of the Maupertuis-like action functional, say $A$. After some straightforward manipulations, $A$ becomes of the form
   $$A[q^2, \ldots, q^n]~=~ \int_{q^1_i}^{q^1_f} d\lambda~ f\left(E,\lambda, q, \frac{dq}{d\lambda}\right) .$$
   It should be straightforward to see which [equations](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=euler%E2%80%93lagrange+equation) describe the stationary points of $A$!

Comment: Ok, but it sort of seems like you have just trivially relabeled the time parameter as a space parameter.